# How to run only once in java while pressing a button?

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to create a game where I have to return a baby when baby goes to Y position at 12 using an button. I want it to be move 2 position from 12 i.e. 10 and move from 10 to 6 but the code move the baby directly to 6. Note: grammar error doesn't let me post icon and baby as a same. It is a variable name.

```
if (baby_posY==12) {
    if (baby_posY==12) {
      tiles[baby_posX][baby_posY].setIcon(null);
      baby_posY=baby_posY-2;
      tiles[baby_posX][baby_posY].setIcon(icon Baby);   
    }
    if (baby_posY==10) {
      tiles[baby_posX][baby_posY].setIcon(null);
      baby_posY=baby_posY-4;
      tiles[baby_posX][baby_posY].setIcon(icon Baby);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Answer (score 0):

You should use else if, instead of if on the subsequent checks. What's happening is 12 is going to 10, then it checks for 10, and makes it 6. Using `else` you can prevent that

```
if (baby_posY==12) { 
    tiles[baby_posX][baby_posY].setIcon(null); baby_posY=baby_posY-2; // **** right here is what's causing the double move
    tiles[baby_posX][baby_posY].setIcon(icon Baby); 
} else if (baby_posY==10) { // adding 'else' will prevent this second condition from triggering if the first was triggered
    tiles[baby_posX][baby_posY].setIcon(null); baby_posY=baby_posY-4; 
    tiles[baby_posX][baby_posY].setIcon(icon Baby); 
}
```

Comment: i want if (baby_posY==10) this condition to work after pressing an button.

Comment: @JohnBista I have erased one of the if statements at the top. This is what is/was preventing if (baby_posY==10) from being executed